# HTML5 canvas image is not visible in chrome

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I am using HTML5 canvas and putting two images there but I am facing one problem which is, one image is loaded and visible in chrome but another image is only visible in mozilla but after refresh. I don't know why this is happening as I am new in canvas.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var width = 900;
var height = 700;
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(imageObj, x, y, width, height);
};
imageObj.src = 'http://img13.deviantart.net/1550/i/2011/353/4/2/mobile_game_background_by_disnie-d4jmr8r.jpg';

var startImageObj = new Image();
startImageObj.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(startImageObj, (canvas.width-startImageObj.width)/2, (canvas.height-startImageObj.height)/2)
};
startImageObj.src = 'http://assets.halfbrick.com/yc/v3/images/button-play.png';
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="900" height="700"></canvas>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cfucxet7/1/)

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: Make sure `http://assets.halfbrick.com/yc/v3/images/button-play.png` is not blocked by your Network Provider.. I got `200 Webcat Access denied` status code in `Network-Tab`

Comment: @Rayon No, I am not getting any error and images are not blocked as I am able to open those images. Those images are just for demo purpose, I am using local images in my system.

Comment: @Rayon Do refresh the page and the image will be gone.

Comment: In firefox all is OK

Comment: @Rayon Go the points, I am creating a html5 canvas game, would you recommend any framework for this?

Comment: @Jason – http://phaser.io/

Comment: @Rayon can you come in chat? I have some conceptual doubts.

Comment: Join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/121048/html5-canvas?tab=general

Answer (score 1):

As [`onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/image.onload) event is asynchronous, make sure `play-button` is being set in the `onload-handler` of the `base-image`

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var width = 900;
var height = 700;
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(imageObj, x, y, width, height);
  var startImageObj = new Image();
  startImageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(startImageObj, (canvas.width - startImageObj.width) / 2, (canvas.height - startImageObj.height) / 2)
  };
  startImageObj.src = 'https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/5670-200.png';
};
imageObj.src = 'http://img13.deviantart.net/1550/i/2011/353/4/2/mobile_game_background_by_disnie-d4jmr8r.jpg';
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="900" height="700"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Rayon's answer is right in that with your current implementation you can't know which image will have loaded first, but IMO it is wrong to wrap everything in the same callback, since you will have to wait for the first image has loaded before trigger the loading of the next one, whcih will produce a flicker apparition of the last image.

Instead, create a preloader function that will trigger a drawing function when both images have been loaded.

This has the advantage to make it easier to call your drawing function later, and also to keep your code a bit cleaner :

```js
/* preloader
  inputs : 
    an array containing the urls of the images to load,
 a callback function called when all the images have loaded 
  outputs: 
    an array containing all the image elements in the same order has the urls where provided 
*/
function preloader(imageURLs, callback) {

  var toLoad = imageURLs.length,
    toReturn = [],
    decrement = function() {
      if (--toLoad <= 0) {
        callback();
      }
    };

  imageURLs.forEach(function(url) {
    var img = new Image()
      // you may want to include a more verbose error function
    img.onload = img.onerror = decrement;
    img.src = url;
    toReturn.push(img);
  });

  return toReturn;
}

function draw() {
  ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(front, (canvas.width - front.width) / 2, (canvas.height - front.height) / 2);
}

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  urls = [
    'http://img13.deviantart.net/1550/i/2011/353/4/2/mobile_game_background_by_disnie-d4jmr8r.jpg',
    'https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/5670-200.png'
  ],
  images = preloader(urls, draw),
  background = images[0],
  front = images[1];
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="900" height="700"></canvas>
```