# How To Wait Image Until Complete Loaded to perform the next operation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, imagesloaded

i'm facing a big problem here every time i call this javascript function it does not wait until the `left` and `right` images to load but it goes immediatly to the next operation and what i want is to stop until `left` and `right` image to load the image perfectly then it goes to `syllable_text.html(slice.The_Syl);` line

```
function showImagesByPairAtInterval(Syllables, interval, index) {
        index = index || 0;
        let slice = Syllables[index];
        left.attr('src', "http://example.com/"+ slice.Url1);
        right.attr('src', "http://example.com/"+ slice.Url2);
        syllable_text.html(slice.The_Syl);
        nextIndex = index + 1;
        if (nextIndex <= Syllables.length - 1) {
            setTimeout(showImagesByPairAtInterval.bind(
                null,
                Syllables,
                interval,
                nextIndex
            ), interval);
        }
}
```

Here how i call this function

```
showImagesByPairAtInterval(syllables.Syllables, 3000);
```

and here the tow images

```
<div id="images" style="display: flex;">
    <img src="" id="left_image" name="left_image" alt="" />
    <img src="" id="right_image" name="right_image" alt="" />
</div>
```

**Updated Script**

after using ImagesLoaded Script which i found in [ImagesLoaded](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/)
like

```
function showImagesByPairAtInterval(Syllables, interval, index) {
        index = index || 0;
        let slice = Syllables[index];
        left.attr('src', "http://deaf-api.azurewebsites.net/"+ slice.Url1);
        right.attr('src', "http://deaf-api.azurewebsites.net/"+ slice.Url2);
        while (!$("#images").imagesLoaded().always()) {
        }
        syllable_text.html(slice.The_Syl);


        nextIndex = index + 1;
        if (nextIndex <= Syllables.length - 1) {
            setTimeout(showImagesByPairAtInterval.bind(
                null,
                Syllables,
                interval,
                nextIndex
            ), interval);
        }
}
```

it seems like it doesn't really care when all the images really finish loading i assume that there is a second way to use this script

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load

Comment: i know that it must be a `ready` event but i don't know how to use it in this sequence

Comment: maybe something like http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/ would be helpful. its otherwise a bit of a pain to check both images are loaded before executing some code in this case.

Comment: do you know how to use it i will update the question above to tell where is the error while using `imagesloaded` script

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38968671/3702797

Answer (score 0):

OK i want to post the solution for this problem since what i think that `ImagesLoaded` Script maybe confused about neither the `left` and `right` images were loaded or not so i decide to make new images which i can tell it's not being yet loaded and after i check it's loaded i change `left` and `right` images like this

```
function showImagesByPairAtInterval(Syllables, interval, index) {
            index = index || 0;
            let slice = Syllables[index];
            var left_img = new Image();
            var right_img = new Image();
            var div_img = document.createElement('div');
            var $div_img = $("<div>");
            $div_img.append(left_img);
            $div_img.append(right_img);
            left_img.src = "example.com/" + slice.Url1;
            right_img.src = "example.com/" + slice.Url2;
            while (!$div_img.imagesLoaded().done()) {
            }
            left.attr('src', "http://example.com/" + slice.Url1);
            right.attr('src', "http://example.com/" + slice.Url2);

            syllable_text.html(slice.The_Syl);


            nextIndex = index + 1;
            if (nextIndex <= Syllables.length - 1) {
                setTimeout(showImagesByPairAtInterval.bind(
                    null,
                    Syllables,
                    interval,
                    nextIndex
                ), interval);
            } 
}
```

Comment: Ouch you'll kill most browsers doing it... don't use a while loop, learn asynchronous code and events handling.

Comment: i'm really stuck in time with this it just a batch for a while i ask here if anybody really find a solution for my problem

Comment: I gave you a link to an answer showing you how to preload multiple images and executing a callback just when all are loaded.