# html5 Canvas drawimage background + 9 images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a little problem, sometimes work or not work drawimage, i tried to begin with draw background and if drawed then next draw 9 images(sometimes images is this same or not same).

```
var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    $('button').on('click',function(){

        var img = new Image();
        var img1 = new Image();
        var img2 = new Image();
        var img3 = new Image();
        var img4 = new Image();
        var img5 = new Image();
        var img6 = new Image();
        var img7 = new Image();
        var img8 = new Image();
        var img9 = new Image();
        img.src = $(location).attr('href')+'/img/frames/'+$('#frames option:selected').val();
        img1.src = $(location).attr('href')+'/img/mercmain/'+$('#merc1 option:selected').val();
        img2.src = $(location).attr('href')+'/img/mercmain/'+$('#merc2 option:selected').val();
        img3.src = $(location).attr('href')+'/img/mercmain/'+$('#merc3 option:selected').val();
        img4.src = $(location).attr('href')+'/img/mercmain/'+$('#merc4 option:selected').val();
        img5.src = $(location).attr('href')+'/img/mercmain/'+$('#merc5 option:selected').val();
        img6.src = $(location).attr('href')+'/img/mercmain/'+$('#merc6 option:selected').val();
        img7.src = $(location).attr('href')+'/img/mercmain/'+$('#merc7 option:selected').val();
        img8.src = $(location).attr('href')+'/img/mercmain/'+$('#merc8 option:selected').val();
        img9.src = $(location).attr('href')+'/img/mercmain/'+$('#merc9 option:selected').val();

        img.onload = function(){
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0,307,382);

            img1.onload = function(){
                ctx.drawImage(img1,$xyframe[0][0],$xyframe[0][1],$xyframe[0][2],$xyframe[0][3]);
            };
            img2.onload = function(){
                ctx.drawImage(img2,$xyframe[1][0],$xyframe[1][1],$xyframe[1][2],$xyframe[1][3]);
            };
            img3.onload = function(){
                ctx.drawImage(img3,$xyframe[2][0],$xyframe[2][1],$xyframe[2][2],$xyframe[2][3]);
            };
            img4.onload = function(){
                ctx.drawImage(img4,$xyframe[3][0],$xyframe[3][1],$xyframe[3][2],$xyframe[3][3]);
            };
            img5.onload = function(){
                ctx.drawImage(img5,$xyframe[4][0],$xyframe[4][1],$xyframe[4][2],$xyframe[4][3]);
            };
            img6.onload = function(){
                ctx.drawImage(img6,$xyframe[5][0],$xyframe[5][1],$xyframe[5][2],$xyframe[5][3]);
            };
            img7.onload = function(){
                ctx.drawImage(img7,$xyframe[6][0],$xyframe[6][1],$xyframe[6][2],$xyframe[6][3]);
            };
            img8.onload = function(){
                ctx.drawImage(img8,$xyframe[7][0],$xyframe[7][1],$xyframe[7][2],$xyframe[7][3]);
            };
            img9.onload = function(){
                ctx.drawImage(img9,$xyframe[8][0],$xyframe[8][1],$xyframe[8][2],$xyframe[8][3]);
            };

        };
    });
```

and link to test script https://tajkjs-olszam.c9users.io/genform/

and if i remove from img1-9.onload, leave ctx.drawimage(img1-9) and make settimeout from 3 to 5 sec then it's ok but i want without settimeout.

```
setTimeout(function(){

               //img.onload = function(){
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0,307,382);
           // };

                ctx.drawImage(img1,$xyframe[0][0],$xyframe[0][1],$xyframe[0][2],$xyframe[0][3]);



                ctx.drawImage(img2,$xyframe[1][0],$xyframe[1][1],$xyframe[1][2],$xyframe[1][3]);


                ctx.drawImage(img3,$xyframe[2][0],$xyframe[2][1],$xyframe[2][2],$xyframe[2][3]);


                ctx.drawImage(img4,$xyframe[3][0],$xyframe[3][1],$xyframe[3][2],$xyframe[3][3]);


                ctx.drawImage(img5,$xyframe[4][0],$xyframe[4][1],$xyframe[4][2],$xyframe[4][3]);


                ctx.drawImage(img6,$xyframe[5][0],$xyframe[5][1],$xyframe[5][2],$xyframe[5][3]);


                ctx.drawImage(img7,$xyframe[6][0],$xyframe[6][1],$xyframe[6][2],$xyframe[6][3]);


                ctx.drawImage(img8,$xyframe[7][0],$xyframe[7][1],$xyframe[7][2],$xyframe[7][3]);


                ctx.drawImage(img9,$xyframe[8][0],$xyframe[8][1],$xyframe[8][2],$xyframe[8][3]);
            },100);
```

this code is work but unfortunately I have use settimeout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 canvas image is not visible in chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38967705/html5-canvas-image-is-not-visible-in-chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to draw on each image load. Use counter for loaded images and run draw function on last load. Also Pablo said right thing - set onload listener before set source. This code should run inside your click listener function

```js
var img;
var counter = 0;
var imagesLength = 9;
var images = [];
var backgroundImage = new Image();
var imgFolder = location.href+'/img/mercmain/';

function drawImages(){
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  ctx.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0,307,382); //draw background
  for ( var i=0; i<imagesLength ; i++ ){ //draw images
    ctx.drawImage(images[i],$xyframe[i][0],$xyframe[i][1],$xyframe[i][2],$xyframe[i][3]);
  }
}

function onLoad(){
  counter++;
  if( counter === imagesLength + 1 ){ // +1 - we must count also background image
    drawImages(); // draw all the images at once
  }
}

for ( var i=0; i<imagesLength ; i++ ){
  img = new Image();
  images.push( img ); // push in array before src,
    // onload should not fire while image is not in array
  img.onload = onLoad; // set onload before src, 
    // image should not load before onload listener is set
  img.src = imgFolder + $('#merc'+ (i+1) +' option:selected').val();
}

// do not forget to set the same for background image
backgroundImage.onload = onLoad;
backgroundImage.src = location.href + '/img/frames/' + $('#frames option:selected').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a race condition: You are loading all the images at the same time, but if the background image is not the first one to be loaded, you are adding the `onload` listeners AFTER the images have been loaded, so the event has already happened and the drawing logic is never executed.

Solution? the `imgN.onload=function() {...}` assignments should be outside the `img.onload` function:

```
$('button').on('click',function(){

    var img = new Image();
    var imgArr=[];
    for (var i=0;i<9;i++) {
        imgArr[i]=new Image();
    }

    img.src = $(location).attr('href')+'/img/frames/'+$('#frames option:selected').val();
    for (var i=0;i<9;i++) {
        imgArr[i].src=$(location).attr('href')+'/img/mercmain/'+$('#merc'+i+' option:selected').val();
    }
    img.onload = function(){
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0,307,382);
    }
    //Here, instead in the previous function
    for (var i=0;i<9;i++) {
        imgArr[i].onload = function(){
            ctx.drawImage(img1,$xyframe[i][0],$xyframe[i][1],$xyframe[i][2],$xyframe[i][3]);
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: i tried this soultion but is not work what i mean. Look for ao formation frame, where is white so this is transparent then i know it's little work, but if is full colors then cover 9 images :(. look for this https://tajkjs-olszam.c9users.io/genform.1/ and select test frame

Comment: I think I did not explain it well... check this.